# How to have two methods in API Controller with same name but different arguments?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to ApiControllers in MVC4 and I need to have to Get in my Api Controller with different set of arguments like below:

```
public Models.Response Get(int skip, int take, int pageSize, int page)
{
    //do something
}

public Models.Response Get(int skip, int take, int pageSize, int page, PersonSearchModel personSearchModel)
{
    //search with search model
}
```

I make a string of "PersonSearchModel" properties and my request look like this: (the instance of search model was empty)

> localhost:3039/api/personapi/?Firstname=&Lastname=&BirthDate=1/1/0001%2012:00:00%20AM&Gender=0&PageIndex=0&PageSize=20&SortExpression=&TotalItemCount=0&TotalPageCount=0&&take=3&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=3

based on what I know from MVC3 it's supposed to map the url to search model and choose the second Get but I get the "Multiple actions were found that match the request" Exception in my firebug. what should I do? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you cannot do in MVC in the controller is overload a functions.

For the extra parameter, set it as optional and check for the default value you assign it.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom attribute derived from ActionMethodSelectorAttribute that would check the request parameters. You need to oveeride the IsValidForRequest method. It could be something like

```
public class RequireRequestValueAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public RequireRequestValueAttribute(valueName)
    {
        ValueName = valueName;
    }
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[ValueName] != null);
        }
    }
    public string ValueName { get; private set; }
}
```

(You could extend it to check for more than one parameter)

You use this attribute with your methods like this

```
public Models.Response Get(int skip, int take, int pageSize, int page)
{
    //do something
}

[RequireRequestValue("personSearchModel")]
public Models.Response Get(int skip, int take, int pageSize, int page, PersonSearchModel personSearchModel)
{
    //search with search model
}
```

This works for me with MVC 3 and I suppose it also should for MVC 4